# How do you craft command blocks because they are out in MCPE now

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Please tell me I really want to know help me here

Comment: I don't understand all the down votes. Just because it is a duplicate question, doesn't mean you need to down-vote it.

Comment: @AmusingThrone the downvotes are likely due to the question body - which is rather useless.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot craft them.  They can only be obtained through cheat commands.

In normal minecraft, you get them by enabling cheats, and then entering this command in chat:

`/give (player name) command_block`